# Google Analytics won't identify tracking

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm breaking my nuts over this all day long.

I have a wordpress site i am trying to attach a GA account to.

I followed the instructions and pasted the code before

yet my status is still "Status: Tracking Not Installed"
and my real time dashboard shows nothing.

this is my code

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-21580912-7', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

this is my site www.nter.com

any help is good. ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tag looks fine after checking with Google Tag Assistant; I can see pageview hits going through. Are you making sure you are not filtering out your own visits? Also, the tracking code usually takes at least 24 hours to register, so if you just installed it then you would need to wait at least that long before seeing data show up in your standard reports (and also for the status to stop showing that tracking is not installed). In the Real-time reports, are you checking your own *simultaneous* visits, meaning you would need to visit your site, and then check right away in the RT reports? You also have an error on your page on line 169, which may or may not be breaking your analytics:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```